# Wordpress not running jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm firing a jQuery script from within the extender custom in Genesis within my Wordpress installation to make the following occur:

**URL contains email:**

Show div: #sociallocker

Hide div: #emaillocker

**URL doesn't contain email:**

Show div: #emaillocker

Hide div: #sociallocker

But nothing is happening! I know the code is good as it works elsewhere. WHy would Wordpress stop this from working and what can I do to fix it?

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) {  //insted of 'str' use document.location.href
        $("#sociallocker").show();
        $("#emaillocker").hide();
    }
    else{
        $("#sociallocker").hide();
        $("#emaillocker").show();
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sociallocker">
Email parameter
</div>

<div id="emaillocker">
No Email parameter
</div>
```

**Live Link**

https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/

Comment: Is that PHP inside you js?

Comment: For one... You have put <script> tags inside your "custom-scripts.js" file. You should probably remove those.

Comment: As said Joonas, your javascript file shouldn't contain any HTML element, only javascript. Furthermore, can you have a look at your developer console (press F12) and copy paste here the errors that show up.

Comment: Execute the code when the page is loaded `$(document).ready(fn)`)

Comment: Thanks all, as mentioned below I've taken it out of <script> tags and replaced the $ sign with 'jQuery' but still no luck. @MarkBaijens do I just need to copy and paste that line?

Comment: @SamJefferies No the ready function requires a function as parameter. If you look it up in the jQuery API you can find examples (or anywhere on google).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any console errors?

WordPress runs jQuery in compatibility/no conflict mode. You need to replace `$` with `jQuery`

Example: `jQuery("#emaillocker").show();`

Edit:

Useful article: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks, I've taken it out of <script> tags and replaced the $ sign with 'jQuery' but still no luck?

Comment: @SamJefferies In the live link you still have script closing element. Do you even check your console errors?

Comment: Hmm it's removed in the back end so must be being added by Genesis. Apologies, I'm very new to Javascript.